# the date in between

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

Table test:

```
    ID    code   vac_date
  419199    1   2004-06-24
  419199    2   2001-10-04
  419199    1   2005-02-09
  419199    2   2001-03-23
  419199    2   2001-03-22
  419199    1   2001-03-22
  419199    1   2001-02-27
  419199    1   2001-04-04
```

I'm trying  contain only `vac_date` that within the 28 days of each other.

```
select ID,   code,  vac_date 
from test as a
where  a.vac_date = a.vac_date - 28
and    a.vac_date = a.vac_date + 28
```

Then the resolve would be like this.

```
  419199    2   2001-03-23
  419199    2   2001-03-22
  419199    1   2001-03-22
  419199    1   2001-02-27
  419199    1   2001-04-04
```

As long as  the date are within 28 days.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What if there is also a date "2001-02-01", that is within 28 days of "02-27" but not of "03-23"? So please explain a bit more about the requirements (as an edit to your question)

Comment: You can read so that your question is better received [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

24 days can go in either direction.  Date/time functions are also very database specific.  The following gives a flavor of what you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and
                    t2.code = t.code and
                    t2.vac_date >= t.vac_date - interval '24 day' and
                    t2.vac_date <= t.vac_date - interval '24 day'
             );
```